# I'm not able to add a figure

Tags: graphics, errors

sorry if my english is not perfect, I'm writing in latex but I've a problem ... this is my code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10 pt]{report}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage[bibstyle=numeric,citestyle=numeric]{biblatex}
\bibliography{Biblio}

\newcommand{\e}{\`e }

\title{title}
\author{Francesco Serra}

\begin{document}

\maketitle
\tableofcontents

\input{Introduzione.tex}

\nocite{*}
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

File "Introduzione.tex" is quite easy

```
\chapter{Introduzione}

something ...

\section{Mammografia e tomografia}
something else 
\begin{figure}[h]
\includegraphics[width=0.7]{./Immagini/Mammo}
\end{figure}
```

All works without problem without the figure, while adding code about figure compiler gives me these errors:

```
Paragraph ended before \Gin@iii was complete

\begin{figure} on input line 12 ended by \end{document}. \end{document}
You can't use `\end' in internal vertical mode \end{document}

\begin{figure} on input line 12 ended by \end{document}. \end{document}

Missing } inserted \end{document}

Emergency stop
No "backend" specified, using Biber backend.
'babel' detected but 'csquotes' missing.
```

Someone can help me? Thank you

Comment: your posted example doesn't load a graphics package at all but I guess you have `\usepackage{graphics}` but you need `\usepackage{graphicx}` with an x for the `width=` syntax.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please add `\usepackage{graphicx}` to your preamble and include the chapter with `\include{Introduzione.tex}`. (And include the Mammo-picture to your post... no, just kidding)

Comment: Also, the optional argument `width=0.7` has no unit.

Comment: Ok thank you to all ... sorry for stupid question

Comment: There's no stupid question, only difficulties that get solved through experience and help from more experienced users